# How to add or remove css classes using custom directive in angular 4?

Tags: angular, directive, angular-directive

I am using custom directive and I want to modify classes of a host element upon clicking. Everyone is suggesting to use HostBinding and I tried it but still not working.

```
  @HostBinding('class') nosorting = 'table-sorting';
  @HostBinding('class') ascending = 'table-sorting_asc';
  @HostBinding('class') descending = 'table-sorting_desc';

  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  onClick(event) {
    if (event.target.nodeName === 'TH') {
      console.log(this.el);
      const target = $(event.target);
      if (target.data('sort')) {
        if (target.hasClass('table-sorting')) {
          this.renderer.addClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'table-sorting_asc');
          this.renderer.removeClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'table-sorting');
        }
        if (target.hasClass('table-sorting_asc')) {
          this.renderer.addClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'table-sorting_desc');
          this.renderer.removeClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'table-sorting_asc');
        }
        if (target.hasClass('table-sorting_desc')) {
          this.renderer.addClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'table-sorting');
          this.renderer.removeClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'table-sorting_desc');
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Can someone in detail tell me how they work and how to use?

Comment: This [**documentation**](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#binding-to-an-input-property) gives you required information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@HostBinding('class.classsName') varName:boolean;
```

all you to do is set the boolean true or false and then the class will be active in the dom.